# Validating Receipts With the App Store from my server

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am using the below code for receipts validation.

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];

NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];

if (!receipt) { 
   /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */
}

/* ... Send the receipt data to your server ... */
```

Where can I add this code in my code and when I call this, every time gettting different receipt id . Any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create one separate class file and add one method inside this class (or you can write this method in AppDelegate.m file)

```
-(void)yourMethodName
{
   NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];

  NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];

  if (!receipt) { 
    /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */
   }

  /* ... Send the receipt data to your server ... */


}
```

to call this method,
from AppDelegate.m class write below code where you want to call.

```
[[AppDelegate sharedAppdelegate] yourMethodName];
```

or from other class

```
[className yourMethodName];
```

try this.

Comment: thanqs for ur rply. I know how to call this method but I'm not understanding this documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html 
If u know some thing please help me.